# Block elements inside a flex container get squeezed. But why?

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox

I wonder why the 8 inline-block elements inside the flex div get squeezed and do not adhere to their setting (`width: 50px`).

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a><a>4</a><a>5</a><a>6</a><a>7</a><a>8</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key here is adding "flex-shrink: 0;" and remove "justify-content: center;"

```css
div
{
 display: flex;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}

a 
{
 display: inline-block;
 background:orange;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 10px;
 flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a><a>4</a><a>5</a><a>6</a><a>7</a><a>8</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zogybegu/

Answer (score -1):

Because its width is set. Just delete `width: 150px;`.

```css
div {
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           border: 1px solid red;
           overflow: auto;
        }

        a {
           display: inline-block;
           background:orange;
           width: 50px;
           height: 50px;
           margin: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<div>
  <a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a><a>4</a><a>5</a><a>6</a><a>7</a><a>8</a>
</div>
```

This works if the space the flex `div` has is big enough for all the children. Otherwise the `div` adapts to the size, making the children smaller.